# Django Sessions not Working on remote server

Tags: django, session

I am trying to use a session variable in my django app

**view.py**

```
def get(self, request):
    room_name = request.session.get('room_name')
    context = app.get_context(room_name)
    context['room_name_create'] = room_name
    context['room_name_check'] = request.session.get('room_name')
    return render(request, self.template, context)
```

**js**

```
console.log('a', context.room_name_create)
console.log('b', context.room_name_check)
```

This works perfectly on my local server.

On the remote server *context.room_name_create* shows a value, but *context.room_name_check* shows as *null* in the browser.

This is only a small app and I have copied all of the source files to the remote server and so all of the source is identical. I have tested this on different browsers

I have run the examples in the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/) in the shell and it works perfectly

Can anyone suggest what I can check to resolve this?

Comment: Where are you set the session variable ? The line like `request.session.set('room_name') =  some_value` is defined where ?

Comment: I don't have a line like that. I don't use it on the local server and I cannot see it in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/) - it only has the get option - with a default value

Comment: You can also set a session variable like so: `request.session['room_name'] = "foo"`. You do not need a setter.

Comment: Yes - that does it - do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with sessions in Django, you generally need to do two things:

**Set the data in the session**

In your case : `room_name = request.session.set('room_name') = some_value` or
`room_name = request.session['room_name'] = some_value`

**Get the data from the session**

In your case : `room_name = request.session.get('room_name')`

**Note :** You need to set data in the session before trying to retrieve it.